# ggplotly barchart and line chart with separate labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have the following dataset:

```
       dput(head(table_age))
structure(list(Age = c("0-19", "20-24", "25-29", "30-34", "35-39", 
"40-44"), Freq_nominal = c(1321, 3446, 5354, 7233, 7471, 6623
), Freq_percent = c(1.92, 5.01, 7.79, 10.52, 10.86, 9.63), Percent = c("1.92%", 
"5.01%", "7.79%", "10.52%", "10.86%", "9.63%"), Nominal = c(1321, 
3446, 5354, 7233, 7471, 6623), female = c(655L, 1473L, 2275L, 
2929L, 3081L, 2830L), male = c(665L, 1918L, 3002L, 4258L, 4347L, 
3762L), female_percent = c(2.2, 4.94, 7.63, 9.82, 10.33, 9.49
), female_percent_label = c("2.2%", "4.94%", "7.63%", "9.82%", 
"10.33%", "9.49%"), male_percent = c(1.73, 4.99, 7.8, 11.07, 
11.3, 9.78), male_percent_label = c("1.73%", "4.99%", "7.8%", 
"11.07%", "11.3%", "9.78%")), .Names = c("Age", "Freq_nominal", 
"Freq_percent", "Percent", "Nominal", "female", "male", "female_percent", 
"female_percent_label", "male_percent", "male_percent_label"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I used ggplotly to interactivly plot the Age as a barchart, and display custom labels in the tooltip with the text parametar.

This is the working code:

```
t <- ggplot(table_age, aes(as.factor(Age), Freq_percent, text1 = Nominal, 
                           text = paste0("Age group: ", Age), text2 = Percent))  +

  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity", fill = "deepskyblue4", width = 0.5) +

  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  theme_minimal()

ggplotly(t, tooltip = c("text1", "text2"))
```

I want to overlay a line/point for each gender on top of the age barchart. In that respect, I have two problems:

1. geom_point gets plotted through plotly, but not geom_line (when static plot it works fine)
2. i don't know how to label the geom_points seperately from the geom_bar

This is my attempt code:

```
t <- ggplot(table_age, aes(as.factor(Age), Freq_percent, text1 = Nominal, 
                           text = paste0("Age group: ", Age), text2 = Percent))  +

  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity", fill = "deepskyblue4", width = 0.5) +

  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  theme_minimal()

t <- t + geom_point(data=table_age, aes(x=Age, y=female_percent), size = 2, color="magenta")
t <- t + geom_line(data=table_age, aes(x=Age, y=female_percent), colour="magenta")

ggplotly(t, tooltip = c("text1", "text2", "female"))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please make your code reproducible by adding the result of `dput(table_age)` to the question?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geom_line()` needs (usually) a `group` aesthetic, which we can set to a constant to have a single group of obs. This will display `geom_line`.

To display different tooltip we can use a single 'hidden' `text` aesthetic (as you already did) and override it.

In this case is better to define the `aes`s inside each `geom` instead of defining inside the initial `ggplot()` call.

On to the code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

t <- ggplot(table_age)  +
    geom_bar(aes(as.factor(Age), 
                 Freq_percent, 
                 #text = paste0("Age group: ", Age), 
                 text1 = Nominal, 
                 text2 = Percent), 
             position = "dodge",
             stat = "identity",
             fill = "deepskyblue4",
             width = 0.5) +
    geom_point(aes(as.factor(Age), 
                   female_percent,
                   text1 = female), 
               size = 2, 
               color="magenta") +
    geom_line(aes(as.factor(Age), 
                  female_percent,
                  group = 1), 
              color = "magenta") +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    xlab("") + 
    ylab("") +
    theme_minimal()
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text1, text2
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text1

t
```

[image]

```r
ggplotly(t, tooltip = c("text1", "text2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Also, your code is neatly structured. I should put some effort into that as well.